# Bind element value from Generic.XML to the value of a custom dependency

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, win-universal-app

To make story short, I have a universal application developed in C#.
I tried making a custom control that has multiple items such as TextBlock. Then I went ahead and created a custom property. Now what I want to do is to bind the Text value of the TextBlock to the custom property.

NetworkOptions.xaml

```
 <Page
x:Class="TT.ConfigurationWindows.NetworkOptions"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TT.ConfigurationWindows"
xmlns:listItems="using:CustomControls.ListItems"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.30*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <listItems:TextAndPicture Text="customProperty" Height="100" Width="700" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You could see that the "Text" property in my TextAndPicture control was set to "customProperty"

I defined this property in this control...

TextAndPicutre.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace CustomControls.ListItems
{
    public sealed class TextAndPicture : Control
    {
        public TextAndPicture()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextAndPicture);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty enables animation, styling, binding, etc.
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Text",                  // The name of the DependencyProperty
                typeof(string),          // The type of the DependencyProperty
                typeof(TextAndPicture),       // The type of the owner of the DependencyProperty
                new PropertyMetadata(default(string))
            );
    }
}
```

Now I would like to bind the value of the property to my TextBlock; This way whenever I call this control and I set the "Text" Property then it would change the TextBlock value of this custom control.

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomControls.ListItems">

    <Style TargetType="local:TextAndPicture">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TextAndPicture">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <Grid Background="White">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.50*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="95*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Name="test" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                            <!--<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Yellow" />-->
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Magenta" />
                            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="Maroon" />

                            <Line Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.5" Y1="1" Y2="1" Fill="Gray" Stretch="Fill" X2="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

NOTE: If there is any better way to achieve my goal please let me know.

Comment: In you Template use `TemplateBinding` instead of `Binding` in your *TextBlock*.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Great, it works. Thanks.